# clang-format malfunctioning(?) Or am I not fully understanding how clang-format works?

Tags: package, formatting, format, clang

I installed the `clang-format` package from melpa.

I then added the following lines to my init file:

```
(require 'clang-format)
```

I then created a test directory, `cpp-proj` with one file, `main.cpp`.


**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "ok\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I then created a `.clang-format` file in the directory using the command:

```
clang-format -style=webkit -dump-config > .clang-format
```

**.clang-format**

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  WebKit
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: false
AlignOperands:   false
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:   
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  IndentBraces:    false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
BreakBeforeBraces: WebKit
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
ColumnLimit:     0
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
ForEachMacros:   [ foreach, Q_FOREACH, BOOST_FOREACH ]
IncludeCategories: 
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: Inner
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Cpp03
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
...
```

I then went back into my `main.cpp` file, with the whole buffer selected and issued the command <kbd>Meta-x clang-format-region</kbd>.

The result:


**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "ok\n" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**This is not correct.**


It should be:


**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "ok\n"
         << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

No matter what style I choose it doesn't work within emacs.


Am I doing something wrong configuring clang-format?

It spits out the correct format when I issue the command

`clang-format -style="<style>" main.cpp` in a terminal, but never in Emacs!

What gives?

Comment: The easiest explanation for this is that the config file is not honored. Some more systematic debugging is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the same thing (not following my styles as defined in a `.clang-format` file, which happens to be in the parent directory in my case), and I think that the problem is in the way that the `assume-file-name` argument is defaulted if absent when calling the function `clang-format-region` from `clang-format.el`:

`(unless assume-file-name
    (setq assume-file-name buffer-file-name))`

Further down, this is passed to the `-assume-filename` command-line option of clang-format. This means that we ask clang-format to look in files with the same name as the current buffer for the style information, which didn't seem like a good default to me. I therefore experimentally altered the default to be `.clang-format`, thus:

`(unless assume-file-name
    (setq assume-file-name '".clang-format"))`

That way we look in the "usual place" for the style info. In my case this solved the problem and my style file is honoured when running clang-format via the emacs function.

It might be preferable to alter the arguments which are passed to the clang-format-region function instead of altering the default like this, but to me `.clang-format` felt like a more sensible default than the name of the current buffer!